# Count times an ID meets a condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to find the number of times a certain condition is met but including zeroes (how many employees with a certain name work under each manager).

Table:

| ID | name | manager_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 |
| 2 | John | 1 |
| 3 | Jane | 2 |
| 4 | John | 3 |

The result should be:

| manager_ID | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |

Using WHERE does not return 0 values:

```
SELECT manager_id, COUNT(*)
FROM employees
WHERE name = 'John'
GROUP BY manager_id
```

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`. Use a case expression to do _conditional aggregation_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use a `CASE` *expression* to do *conditional aggregation*.

```
SELECT manager_id,
       sum(case when name = 'John' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM employees
GROUP BY manager_id;
```

Comment: Nice! You could also `count(case name when 'John' then 1 end)` which is the same I guess.

Comment: @KjetilS., yes, that works too (but will give the somewhat unnecessary warning '_null value eliminated in set function_'.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select
e1.manager_id, count(e2.id)
from employees e1
left outer join employees e2 on e1.id = e2.id and e2.name = 'John'
group by e1.manager_id
order by e1.manager_id
;
```